# Creating Image control dynamically inside a listbox based on number of items user wants using C#

Tags: c#, windows-phone-7

Simple question but I am totally confused. I am developing a wp7 app using C#. I want a listbox with input number of image item which source should be same i.e. the list box should contain 'n' Image control with source set to a single image where 'n' is number of Listbox Item enter by user. e.g. If the user input '10', then the listbox should have ten items. I want the listbox ItemsPanelTemplate as Wrap-panel. Can somebody suggest me how to get this?

Comment: Lets assume user entered 10. Then from where you will get the 10 Images source? You alyready have the set of images or you have to get from any service? elaborate a bit

Comment: @nkchandra I have included an image called user.jpg in my project and I want all the images to have the same source i.e. user.jpg

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Define a ListBox in your XAML something like this

```
<ListBox x:Name="ListBoxImages">
    <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
           <StackPanel>
              <Image Source="{Binding Imagesource}" Width="300"/>
           </StackPanel>
        </DataTemplate>
    </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
</ListBox>
```

and then set its Source in the code behind like this

```
int noOfImages = 10; //Take the input from user
List<ImageClass> imageList = new List<ImageClass>();
for(int i=0; i<noOfImages; i++)
imageList.Add(new ImageClass() { Imagesource = "/user.jpg" });

ListBoxImages.ItemsSource = imageList; //Set the source of the listbox here
```

where ImageClass is,

```
public class ImageClass
{
    public String Imagesource { get; set; }
}
```

The above is a sample for your understanding. Please customize wisely to suit your needs

Comment: I have done the same thing but the images are not coming. There is no error also. I have debug also, everything is fine but the listbox is empty.

Comment: Yes, I have set the Build Action to Content

Comment: This is the tested and working code. I doubt about the path of the image, "/user.jpg" or "user.jpg" . Also check whether you placed the image directly in the project or in any folder like "/images/user.jpg"!!!  And to check this, create an `<Image Source="/user.jpg" />` tag and see whether it renders the image or not